# How can I set the output device in Flutter with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code for building a flutter app ( on Mac operating system) and I'm usually using a Pixel 7 as output device. But when I run the app in Debug Mode, then it opens the Web-App-Version instead of launching on the Pixel 7. How can I change the Output Device in VS Code? Many thanks for the help.

Comment: check this out. https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/vs-code#selecting-a-target-device

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your device to your computer with a USB cable. Once your sure it's connected you can run `flutter run`.  It will automatically detect your Pixel 7 and run it there.

To make sure it's connected you can run `flutter devices`, it will show the list of devices available.

Comment: Thanks, this is another opportunity, I'll try that.